# How to make a post method ajax call by passing the entities in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, rest

I need to make a post ajax request, where in i need to pass entity classes as parameter.

for eg:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    public bool SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        //inserting the data to database.
    }
```

here my entity class is Employee which has 2,3 properties exposed, say empId,employeename and age.

These informations i need to pass from javascript.

```
   function SaveEmployee() {

var employeename='test';
var age=23;
var empid=34534;
//these data's i need to pass to the ajax method.
        var am = new Proxy();
        am.invoke("SaveEmployee", { **here how can i pass my entity Employee?** }, function(response){
             if (response) {
```

can i do something like this in the javascript?

```
var employee=new Employee();
employee.Name=employeename;
employee.Age=age;
employee.EmpId=empid;
and  am.invoke("SaveEmployee", { "Employee":employee },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample I put together that POSTs an entity to a WCF REST service (using jQuery on the client side).  If you're not using jQuery, I think you'll still see how to handle it.

Here's the HTML & JavaScript:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
    Desc: <input type="text" id="desc" /><br />
    <button id="submit">Send!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var theData = {};
                theData["Name"] = $("#name").val();
                theData["Desc"] = $("#desc").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ProdService.svc/product/add",
                    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (e, t, x) {
                        alert(t);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The key things to note is that I'm setting the content type of the request to `application/json`.  That's key for WCF so it knows what's being sent up.

My service is defined as such:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate="product/add")]
String AddProduct(Product p)
{
    return "Got " + p.Name;
}
```

And my entity is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember()]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public String Desc { get; set; }
}
```

My web.config is set up like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebApplication2.ProdServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="WebApplication2.ProdService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication2.ProdServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication2.ProdService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The key in the web.config is that my `endpointBehavior` uses `webHttp` instead of `enableWebScript`.  Other than that, this is pretty much an out-of-the-box configuration.

So the keys are that my payload is a JavaScript object literal converted to a JSON-ized string.  My service is expecting the request format to be JSON, and since my `Product` class is decorated with the `DataMember` and `DataContract` attributes, it can deserialize my payload to a `Product` class instance.

I hope this helps.  Please let me know if you have other questions and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi.. I am not using wcf. I am using my existing Entities. Its a huge application. hence i cannot change any of the properties. Can u please tell the how can i do for the other regular entities.